# Hibernate: Transitive persistance of set of objects in an @ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, many-to-many

I am trying to map the following:

```
public class Person{
  ...
  @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
  @JoinTable(name = "person_categories", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "personId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "categoryId"))
  private Set<Category> categories

  ...
}

public class Category {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "categoryId")
  private Integer id;

  @Column(unique = true)
  private Sting name

  ...
}
```

When I attempt to save a Person object, the categories are inserted, but duplicates are stored into the table.  How can I ensure each category is unique in its table and while maintaining transitive persistence?  I have tried making the name column unique, but that only helped by throwing constraint errors.

Comment: So you're saying that in the table person_categories, you'll find multiple rows with the exact same data (reference to person and to category)?

Comment: Multiple rows of the same category are being inserted into the Category table.  I want the Category table to act as a Set, where an insert will only happen when the record does not already exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't override hashCode() and equals() to be meaningful for the *Category* class, then you will get duplicates in your Set (if you're adding duplicates to begin with).  If the *name* field is what differentiates objects, try:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return name.hashCode();
}

public Object equals (Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Category) {
        return ((Category)o).name.equals(this.name);
    }
    return false;
}
```